# Epson GT-S50 scanner not working after upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, 18.04, scanner, epson

Since the upgrade, my Epson scanner GT-S50 (Epkowa driver).
It gets detected (`dmesg`) when plugged in:

```
[ 3755.680091] usb 3-4.4.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 3755.789893] usb 3-4.4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b8, idProduct=0137
[ 3755.789895] usb 3-4.4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3755.789896] usb 3-4.4.1: Product: EPSON Scanner
[ 3755.789897] usb 3-4.4.1: Manufacturer: EPSON
```

But when starting either "Image Scan!" or "Simple scan", no scanner can be detected.

[image: Image Scan! Error]

It still somehow gets detected by Sane, because when running sane-find-scanner, it "sees" it:

```
...
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [Language Error], product=0x0137 [Language Error]) at libusb:003:008
...
```

However, `scanimage -L` fails to detect it!

> No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).

If I can't find a solution, I'll consider downgrading back to 16.04.

Extra information after some extra investigation: it seems that the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 broke something within the Sane setup. Calling `iscan` or other sane related applications lead all to fail discovering my scanner due to the following error from syslog:

```
iscan: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
```

Other calls to sane utilities fail for the same reason:

```
colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
scanimage: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
xsane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
```

**EDIT 2**: Ok, found & solved the origin of the `io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1` messages; it is caused by the hplip's (libsane's) hpio module. I've disabled it (= commented out in `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip` file) and the message is now gone.

Besides, I've tried to specify my scanner to sane by adding `usb 0x04b8 0x0137` in the `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` file *and* added the following UDEV rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` as file `55-libsane.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0137", MODE="0666", 
GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

But, so far still no avail... scanner stubbornly undetected :'(

Side note: don't know if that matters, but when disconnecting the scanner, I see the following message appear in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 16 09:37:40 hades kernel: [22174.197243] usb 3-4.4.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
May 16 09:37:40 hades upowerd[1809]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.2/usb3/3-4/3-4.4/3-4.4.1
May 16 09:37:40 hades colord-sane[7678]: failed to receive list of devices: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs_EPSON_EPSON_Scanner
```

Comment: very well researched and documented; I hope you have reported this as a bug to ubuntu; they need this

Comment: Hi pdc, thanks for the advice :-) There is actually already a bug filed in Ubuntu's sane-backend package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012. I've added my observations to it in a comment. Hoping they'll soon find a solution. Cheers, Manu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a word an affective workaround in the comments of the [Ubuntu's sane-backends bug #1728012](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012). I documented it as a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012/comments/130) on the bug report.

The problem seems to reside in missing symlinks to the epkowa (SEIKO EPSON) libraries in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane` (or, more generically, `/usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/sane`) folder.

I thus did the following:

1. `sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`
2. Removed the `usb 0x04b8 0x0137` entry I had added to `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`
3. Added a `55-epson-libsane.rules` file to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with the following text:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"

   ATTRS{manufacturer}=="EPSON", DRIVERS=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0666"

   ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0137", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```
4. Finally I unplugged / plugged my scanner and tried

   ```
   scanimage -L
   ```

   and got this encouraging answer:

   ```
   device `epkowa:interpreter:003:011' is a Epson GT-S50 flatbed scanner
   ```
5. Then I started `iscan` (Image Scan!) and it immediately detected my scanner. I then could successfully scan a page. Yipee! :-)

**UPDATE: (Ubuntu 20.04)**
I suddenly got the issue back after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.
I searched quite a bit because nothing seemingly changed in my config... and all of a sudden I noticed that somehow my `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` file's permissions had been altered and that the file was only readable for root !

After changing it back to "world" readable (`chmod +r /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` ) everything went back to normal and both iscan and scanimage would again be able to detect the scanner properly without having to be invoked using "sudo".

Comment: well done; great research

Comment: Thank you for this! I had a similar problem with Brother DCP-J315W. Adding symlinks to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane` solved the problem.

Comment: I followed your exact instructions with the exception of the vendor and product ID in the 55-epson-libsane.rules file. I had to change them to match my Epson V19 scanner. I was able to get the IDs by running the command sane-find-scanner.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my Epson DS-30 scanner as well.

One observation: I think your "55-epson-libsane.rules" is overkill. I'm pretty sure all but the last line can be deleted.

In my case (for Epson DS-30 scanner) my entire file was one line:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0147", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`

Comment: @BenjaminKraus: You're welcome, glad to know it helped. Besides, you're probably right about my UDEV rule, but at the time, I was experimenting and among the various suggestions in the thread about the libsane-backend bug, it was one of the recommendations, hence my try :-)

Comment: Step 2 is only necessary when `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` has been previously manually edited.

Comment: Worked with my Epson Perfection V33 on Ubuntu 18.04, thanks so much! Did not have to modify the epkowa.conf file.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the feedback, glad it helped you ;-)