# Ubuntu 18.04: scanner program does not detect scanner

Tags: scanner

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04. I installed the Seiko scanner program per their instructions. I checked it using terminal and the Bash command "lsusb" and the hardware detects the scanner. I use "Classic menu indicator" and it sees the scanner program; however, when I click on the program name, "image scan!for Linux" I get a message "could not send command to scanner. Check the scanners status". Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: can you tell us the name and model number of your scanner please: Seiko seems also to be Epson;

Comment: My scanner is an Epson Perfection V500 Photo.  model J251A.  SN  K5ZW013161

Answer (score 8):

## Add a link & a file

The problem stems from missing symbolic links in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane` (or, more generically, `/usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/sane`) to the [Epson driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) directory.

```
$ sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

Furthermore, a `55-epson-libsane.rules` file needs to be added to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory with the following contents:

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", MODE=="0666"

    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="EPSON", DRIVERS=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0666"

    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0137", MODE="0666", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

After power cycling the scanner, the following command should now properly list the connected scanner:

```
$ scanimage -L

device `epkowa:interpreter:003:002' is a Epson GT-S50 flatbed scanner
```

Use `xsane` or the proprietary [Epson `iscan`](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) to operate the scanner.

Comment: This also helped me with my Brother MFC-7340 scanner. The same issue with links. https://askubuntu.com/a/1054065/54548 <= This answer has the details for that scanner brand.

Comment: Just want to say thanks for this. After spending a few days on google searching for an answer this worked!  I have an ubuntu 18.04 machine with an epson v370 photo scanner.  This got it to work!  thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This recent thread seems to provide the answer:

[Epson GT-S50 scanner not working after upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034528/epson-gt-s50-scanner-not-working-after-upgrade-to-18-04-from-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1687522_1034528)

Two parts:

1. Create symbolic links
2. Add a `55-epson-libsane.rules` file to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

The symbolic link is:

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

and the above thread gives more details on part 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the 32-bit system use this symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane
```

and rest like previous answers