# Brother MFC-495CW Scanner not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: scanner

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and my scanner, Brother MFC-495CW, is working fine.  However I wanted to test Ubuntu 18.04 and installed it on a separate hard-drive.  I followed the same instructions as for 16.04 but cannot make the scanner work on 18.04.  When using "Simple Scan" I get Failed to scan, no scanners available.  Please connect a scanner.  Please help.

Answer (score 6):

from this thread, post #25

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012

add these two symbolic links

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib64/libbrscandec* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

(ie you need to copy each command above; line by line; paste into a terminal; hit the ENTER key and move to second line ..)
re-boot ....... any joy?

Comment: Thank you! The symlinks were just what was needed to fix the scan function on a Brother MFC-6490CW under Ubuntu 18.04. The bug report mentions that this applies to all Brother scanners before brscan4 (loads of DCP and MFC models), the Dell MFP Laser Printer 1135n, Epson scanners supported by the libsane-epk driver or the iscan driver, several Epson Perfection models and the WorkForce GT-1500, the Samsung M2070, and the Xerox Workcentre 3225, though the [paths are slightly different](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012/comments/36) for the non-Brother devices.